# VBScript file is self deleted even without being executed

Tags: vbscript

I have VBScript that launches TestNG tests. Before calling tests it should download .jar files of application under test. Here is the main part of the code:

```
'Variables - input args
Dim objArgs
Set objArgs = wscript.Arguments
finalHour = CInt(objArgs(1))

Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

'save script stating date
startDay = Day(Now)
startHour = Hour(Now)

downloadLink = "http://....ru:.../.../"
savePath = "C:\monitoring\build-under-test\"

WScript.Echo "Download jar files from '" & downloadLink & "...'"

'DownloadFile downloadLink   & "some.jar",    savePath & "some.jar"
Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Dim bStrm: Set bStrm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", downloadLink & "account.jar", False
xHttp.Send

With bStrm
    .Type = 1 '//binary
    .Open
    .Write xHttp.ResponseBody
    .SaveToFile savePath & "account.jar", 1 '//overwrite
    .Close
End With
xHttp = Nothing
bStrm = Nothing

Do
    WScript.Echo "Executing: run-suite.bat " & objArgs(0) & "        - at " & Now
    WScript.Echo "    finalHour = " & finalHour
    'With waiting of last command execution
    oShell.Run "run-suite.bat " & objArgs(0) & " " & objArgs(1) & " false true > C:\monitoring\results\logfiles\" & logBatName, 1, True

    currentHour = Hour(Now)
    WScript.Echo "    checking: currentHour < finalHour :: " & currentHour & " < " & finalHour
Loop While currentHour < finalHour
```

The problem is that when I executed this file:

```
cscript.exe "run-monitoring.vbs" "test-suite\monitoring-all-tests.xml" 21
```

This file deleted itself. Then after I recreated the file, it deleted itself again without run command. So I started to recreate it and comment lines to find the line which forces deletion of the file. It was:

```
.SaveToFile savePath & "account.jar", 1 '//overwrite
```

When I remove comment, file deletes itself. Even after PC restart.

Why is it so? Why is file reexecuted even when I do not run it?

Comment: For me, it is being detected as `TrojanDownloader.HTML/Adodb.gen!A` by Windows Defender and moved to quarantine. Check your antivirus log.

Comment: *\*facepalm\**.

Answer (score 0):

There are two lines of code that work with the same resources (.jar files)

```
.SaveToFile savePath & "account.jar", 1 '//overwrite
```

and (java tests that use this lib):

```
oShell.Run "run-suite.bat " & objArgs(0) & " " & objArgs(1) & " false true > C:\monitoring\results\logfiles\" & logBatName, 1, True
```

Commenting any of these lines fixes self-deleting. So solution I used is quite simple: move .jar file saving operation to another vbscript file `download-jar.vbs` and call it in the script:

```
oShell.run "cscript.exe download-jar.vbs " & downloadJarsLink, 1, True
```

Maybe there is another way (release resources after saving) but I need fast and steady solution, and here it is.